# Asynchronous ReadDirectoryChangesW call blocks the thread from exiting

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, asynchronous, readdirectorychangesw

### Introduction:

I am writing a small app that monitors a certain directory for newly added files.

I would like to put the monitoring code in a separate thread, so I can leave the main thread free for other stuff and cancel the monitoring thread when I need to.

### Relevant Information:

- I am using [ReadDirectoryChangesW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx) to do the monitoring
- I am using raw WIN32 API for thread creation/synchronization
- I am trying to support Windows XP onward.

### Problem:

I was able to code everything properly, except for one thing:

I cannot exit the monitoring thread properly, hence this post.

I am signaling an event object in the main thread, wait for the thread to exit, and then do clean up.

The problem lies in my usage of `ReadDirectoryChangesW` since everything works fine after I comment out that piece of code.

Once the event handle is signaled, `ReadDirectoryChangesW` blocks the thread which prevents it to "catch" the event and exit. If I add a new file in the directory it "unblocks" `ReadDirectoryChangesW`, thread "catches" the event and exits.

To help further, I have made a small [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) below, which illustrates what I have stated so far.

### MVCE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <map>

struct SThreadParams
{
    HANDLE hEvent;
    HANDLE hDir;
    int processDirectoryChanges(const char *buffer)
    {
        if (NULL == buffer) return -1;

        DWORD offset = 0;
        char fileName[MAX_PATH] = "";
        FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION *fni = NULL;

        do
        {
            fni = (FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION*)(&buffer[offset]);
            // since we do not use UNICODE, 
            // we must convert fni->FileName from UNICODE to multibyte
            int ret = ::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, fni->FileName,
                fni->FileNameLength / sizeof(WCHAR),
                fileName, sizeof(fileName), NULL, NULL);

            switch (fni->Action)
            {
            case FILE_ACTION_ADDED:     
            {
                std::cout << "FILE_ACTION_ADDED " << fileName << std::endl;
            }
            break;
            case FILE_ACTION_REMOVED:
            {
                std::cout << "FILE_ACTION_REMOVED " << fileName << std::endl;
            }
            break;
            case FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED:
            {
                std::cout << "FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED " << fileName << std::endl;
            }
            break;
            case FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_OLD_NAME:
            {
                std::cout << "FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_OLD_NAME " << fileName << std::endl;
            }
            break;
            case FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_NEW_NAME:
            {
                std::cout << "FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_NEW_NAME " << fileName << std::endl;
            }
            break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            // clear string so we can reuse it
            ::memset(fileName, '\0', sizeof(fileName));
            // advance to next entry
            offset += fni->NextEntryOffset;

        } while (fni->NextEntryOffset != 0);

        return 0;
    }
};

DWORD WINAPI thread(LPVOID arg)
{
    SThreadParams p = *((SThreadParams *)arg);
    OVERLAPPED ovl = { 0 };
    DWORD bytesTransferred = 0, error = 0;
    char buffer[1024];

    if (NULL == (ovl.hEvent = ::CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL)))
    {
        std::cout << "CreateEvent error = " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return ::GetLastError();
    };

    do {

        if (::ReadDirectoryChangesW(p.hDir, buffer, sizeof(buffer), FALSE,
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME,
            NULL, &ovl, NULL))
        {
            if (::GetOverlappedResult(p.hDir, &ovl, &bytesTransferred, TRUE))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) std::cout << '=';
                std::cout << std::endl;

                if (-1 == p.processDirectoryChanges(buffer))
                    std::cout << "processDirectoryChanges error = " << std::endl;
            }
            else
            { 
                bytesTransferred = 0;
                std::cout << "GetOverlappedResult error = " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
            }

            if (0 == ::ResetEvent(ovl.hEvent))
            {
                std::cout << "ResetEvent error = " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
                ::CloseHandle(ovl.hEvent);
                return ::GetLastError();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // we shall just output the error, and try again...
            std::cout << "ReadDirectoryChangesW error =  " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
        }

        error = ::WaitForSingleObject(p.hEvent, 2000);

    } while (WAIT_TIMEOUT == error);

    ::CloseHandle(ovl.hEvent);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    SThreadParams s;
    
    s.hDir = ::CreateFile(SOME_DIRECTORY,
            FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
            NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);
    
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == s.hDir)
    {
        std::cout << "CreateFile error = " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    s.hEvent = ::CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    
    if (NULL == s.hEvent)
    {
        std::cout << "CreateEvent error = " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
        ::CloseHandle(s.hDir);
        return 1;
    }
    
    HANDLE hThread = ::CreateThread(NULL, 0, thread, (LPVOID)&s, 0, NULL);
    
    if (NULL == hThread)
    {
        std::cout << "CreateThread error = " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
        ::CloseHandle(s.hDir);
        ::CloseHandle(s.hEvent);
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "press any key to close program..." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    
    if (0 == ::CancelIoEx(s.hDir, NULL))
    {
        std::cout << "CancelIoEx error = " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
        ::CloseHandle(s.hDir);
        ::CloseHandle(s.hEvent);
        return 1;
    }

    if (0 == ::SetEvent(s.hEvent))
    {
        std::cout << "SetEvent error = " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
        ::CloseHandle(s.hDir);
        ::CloseHandle(s.hEvent);
        return 1;
    }

    // wait for thread to exit
    DWORD error = ::WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    std::cout << "Thread exited with error code = " << error << std::endl;

    ::CloseHandle(s.hEvent);
    ::CloseHandle(s.hDir);
    ::CloseHandle(hThread);

    return 0;
}
```

### My Efforts to Solve:

- I have moved out `OVERLAPPED` structure out of thread into structure that was passed to thread. Then I set `OVERLAPPED.hEvent` to forcibly "unblock" `ReadDirectoryChangesW`. This seems to work, but scares me because I think it is not safe/error prone since it is undocumented.
- I have tried to use completion routines but got no success since I am new with all this. I was able to receive notifications, but content of the buffer (the one filled with `ReadDirectoryChangesW`) was not read properly after the first pass. I am still trying to make this work on my own, but could use help.
- I could use I/o completion port, but since I will monitor only one directory I think this is a bit of an overkill. If I am mistaken, please instruct me how to use I/o completion port for my case, I would love to try them out.

### Question:

Given the MVCE above, can you instruct me on how to modify the code in the thread procedure, so it exits properly (without `ReadDirectoryChangesW` blocking).

*I have a feeling that i will have to use completion routines. In that case I would humbly ask for some pseudo code or written instructions since this would be my first time using them.*

Each time I made a progress, I will update this post with relevant data accordingly.

Comment: What's the weird endless loop event create/destroy stuff all about? Smells like cargo cult programming.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I do not know how to properly structure program flow to handle those errors. Can you help with the actual problem stated in the question?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I have rewritten the code in accordance with your suggestions...

Comment: Use a second event to signal that the thread should exit, and use `WaitForMultipleObjects` instead of `GetOverlappedResult`. Note that your title is misleading. `ReadDirectoryChangesW` is not blocking. It's `GetOverlappedResult` that is blocking.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Thank you, If you put your comment as an answer i will officially accept it and upvote.

Comment: Go ahead and write your own answer and accept it.

Comment: The documentation says you need to open the directory with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` for asynchronous operation.

Answer (score 0):

exist 3 ways to do asynchronous operation with file:

- use ApcRoutine
- use IoCompletionPort
- use Event - worst

you select worst variant. i be use IoCompletionPort on your place. in this case you not need create events, threads, call `GetOverlappedResult`, not need any loops..

all what need call [`BindIoCompletionCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363484(v=vs.85).aspx) (or `RtlSetIoCompletionCallback`) on file and all !

about cancelation - [`CancelIoEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363792(v=vs.85).aspx) not exist in XP ("I am trying to support Windows XP"
), 
but you can simply close directory handle - in this case IO will be canceled with [`STATUS_NOTIFY_CLEANUP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx). so code can look like this:

```
RUNDOWN_REF_EVENT g_rundown; // Run-Down Protection

class SPYDATA : 
#ifdef _USE_NT_VERSION_
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK
#else
    OVERLAPPED 
#endif
{
    HANDLE _hFile;
    LONG _dwRef;
    union {
        FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION _fni;
        UCHAR _buf[PAGE_SIZE];
    };

    void DumpDirectoryChanges()
    {
        union {
            PVOID buf;
            PBYTE pb;
            PFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION pfni;
        };

        buf = _buf;

        for (;;)
        {
            DbgPrint("%x <%.*S>\n", pfni->Action, pfni->FileNameLength >> 1, pfni->FileName);

            ULONG NextEntryOffset = pfni->NextEntryOffset;

            if (!NextEntryOffset)
            {
                break;
            }

            pb += NextEntryOffset;
        }
    }

#ifdef _USE_NT_VERSION_
    static VOID WINAPI _OvCompRoutine(
        _In_    NTSTATUS dwErrorCode,
        _In_    ULONG_PTR dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
        _Inout_ PIO_STATUS_BLOCK Iosb
        )
    {
        static_cast<SPYDATA*>(Iosb)->OvCompRoutine(dwErrorCode, (ULONG)dwNumberOfBytesTransfered);
    }
#else
    static VOID WINAPI _OvCompRoutine(
        _In_    DWORD dwErrorCode, // really this is NTSTATUS
        _In_    DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
        _Inout_ LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
        )
    {
        static_cast<SPYDATA*>(lpOverlapped)->OvCompRoutine(dwErrorCode, dwNumberOfBytesTransfered);
    }
#endif

    VOID OvCompRoutine(NTSTATUS status, DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered)
    {
        DbgPrint("[%x,%x]\n", status, dwNumberOfBytesTransfered);

        if (0 <= status) 
        {
            if (status != STATUS_NOTIFY_CLEANUP)
            {
                if (dwNumberOfBytesTransfered) DumpDirectoryChanges();
                DoRead();
            }
            else
            {
                DbgPrint("\n---- NOTIFY_CLEANUP -----\n");
            }
        }

        Release();
        g_rundown.ReleaseRundownProtection();
    }

    ~SPYDATA()
    {
        Cancel();
    }

public:

    void DoRead()
    {
        if (g_rundown.AcquireRundownProtection())
        {
            AddRef();
#ifdef _USE_NT_VERSION_
            NTSTATUS status = ZwNotifyChangeDirectoryFile(_hFile, 0, 0, this, this, &_fni, sizeof(_buf), FILE_NOTIFY_VALID_MASK, TRUE);
            if (NT_ERROR(status))
            {
                OvCompRoutine(status, 0);
            }
#else
            if (!ReadDirectoryChangesW(_hFile, _buf, sizeof(_buf), TRUE, FILE_NOTIFY_VALID_MASK, (PDWORD)&InternalHigh, this, 0))
            {
                OvCompRoutine(RtlGetLastNtStatus(), 0);
            }
#endif
        }
    }

    SPYDATA()
    {
        _hFile = 0;// ! not INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE because use ntapi for open file
        _dwRef = 1;
#ifndef _USE_NT_VERSION_
        RtlZeroMemory(static_cast<OVERLAPPED*>(this), sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
#endif
    }

    void AddRef()
    {
        InterlockedIncrement(&_dwRef);
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_dwRef))
        {
            delete this;
        }
    }

    BOOL Create(POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES poa)
    {
        IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
        NTSTATUS status = ZwOpenFile(&_hFile, FILE_GENERIC_READ, poa, &iosb, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE);
        if (0 <= status)
        {
            return
#ifdef _USE_NT_VERSION_
            0 <= RtlSetIoCompletionCallback(_hFile, _OvCompRoutine, 0);
#else
            BindIoCompletionCallback(_hFile, _OvCompRoutine, 0);
#endif
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    void Cancel()
    {
        if (HANDLE hFile = InterlockedExchangePointer(&_hFile, 0))
        {
            NtClose(hFile);
        }
    }
};

void DemoF()
{
    if (g_rundown.Create())
    {
        STATIC_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES(oa, "\\systemroot\\tmp");//SOME_DIRECTORY

        if (SPYDATA* p = new SPYDATA)
        {
            if (p->Create(&oa))
            {
                p->DoRead();
            }

            MessageBoxW(0, L"wait close program...", L"", MB_OK);

            p->Cancel();

            p->Release();
        }

        g_rundown.ReleaseRundownProtection();
        g_rundown.WaitForRundown();
    }
}
```

for wait when all IO finished i use [Run-Down Protection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj569382(v=vs.85).aspx). unfortunately this is not implemented in user mode, but not hard implement this very useful feature yourself. my implementation:

```
class __declspec(novtable) RUNDOWN_REF
{
    LONG _LockCount;

protected:

    virtual void RundownCompleted() = 0;

public:

    RUNDOWN_REF()
    {
        _LockCount = 1;
    }

    BOOL AcquireRundownProtection()
    {
        LONG LockCount = _LockCount, prevLockCount;

        do 
        {
            if (!LockCount)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            LockCount = InterlockedCompareExchange(&_LockCount, LockCount + 1, prevLockCount = LockCount);

        } while (LockCount != prevLockCount);

        return TRUE;
    }

    void ReleaseRundownProtection()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_LockCount))
        {
            RundownCompleted();
        }
    }
};

class RUNDOWN_REF_EVENT : public RUNDOWN_REF
{
    HANDLE _hEvent;

    virtual void RundownCompleted()
    {
        SetEvent(_hEvent);
    }

public:

    BOOL Create()
    {
        return (_hEvent = CreateEvent(0, TRUE, FALSE, 0)) != 0;
    }

    RUNDOWN_REF_EVENT()
    {
        _hEvent = 0;
    }

    ~RUNDOWN_REF_EVENT()
    {
        if (_hEvent) CloseHandle(_hEvent);
    }

    void WaitForRundown()
    {
        if (WaitForSingleObject(_hEvent, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0) __debugbreak();
    }
};
```

Comment: First off, thank you for answering. *you select worst variant. i be use IoCompletionPort on your place.* I saw no benefit of creating IOCP for only 1 folder, to monitor only for new files added. However, I am currently reading documentation for `BindIoCompletionCallback` (I never heard of it until now) and I feel that your approach does seem better, *if* I have understood you right (which I am not sure at the moment). Give me time to read through the links you provided and to study your code, since I would really like to go "IO completion port" route.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff what problem create IOCP (even indirect in current case) ? what different 1 folder or many. create events better ? also in case events ASIO we have no additional context. in case APC or IOCP - have. because this events and wort. in case events we must wait. in other case we never wait - simply callback called. of course if you never before use IOCP(BindIoCompletionCallback) will hard understand my code

Comment: *of course if you never before use IOCP(BindIoCompletionCallback) will hard understand my code* Exactly, everything in your code is new to me. I got the task (from my OP) from senior developer in my company so I was doing everything on my own. I came up with the solution I posted, but knew it was not the best one.  Still, I will invest effort to understand your code because i agree that IOCP is the best route, I just do not know how to implement them properly. Thanks again.